# UIAlertController not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to display a message to my users with alert controller but it wont show

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Incorrect username/password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you haven't presented it yet. paste this code where you want to show the alert

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```